# How do I copy udev rules to the right place? Likely a simple question, but I cannot find a tutorial or anything on how to do it

Tags: steam, udev, sony

I want to copy [this](https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv/blob/master/udev/50-ds4drv.rules) code into /etc/udev/rules.d/. At first I tried to drag a text file named *50-ds4drv.rules* into it, but lo, I was not allowed, obvious in hindsight.

I am aware that I need to use the terminal, but which commands should I be using exactly? If you could link the right tutorial, or even the right search times that'd be grand.

Thanks.

p.s. - Trying to get a Dualshock 4 controller working with a certain game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use plain old `cp` (copy):

1. `sudo cp /path/to/your/50-ds4drv.rules /etc/udev/`

Another way is to copy the text into a new file

1. `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/50-ds4drv.rules`
2. Paste the text into the file. (Note: CTRL+V *won't* work)
3. Use CTRL+X to end and save your nano session.

Answer (score 2):

Your udev rules are located at /etc/udev/rules.d/
Since that directory is NOT in your home directory, you do not have any right to drag something there. Which is good.
Open a terminal and type

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/50-ds4drv.rules
```

copy and paste the contents of that file into nano (use context menu)

Press Crtl+X to save it. Now you're back in the terminal. You need to tell UDEV, that something has changed:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Now you're set, and you're rules should be applied